How to parse ffmpeg -list_options output to get complete list of formats?
On my Windows 10, application I use VB6 and ffmpeg.exe to capture video from USB capture device.
I need to show complete list of supported formats by this capture card.
When I use below command I get some list.
But its looks incomplete for me.

    ffmpeg -f dshow -list_options true -i video="USB3. 0 capture"


Result:
USB3. 0 capture:
 Q:\FFMpeg VB6\f2>ffmpeg -f dshow -list_options true -i video="USB3. 0 capture"
[dshow @ 087d7480] DirectShow video device options (from video devices)
[dshow @ 087d7480]  Pin "Capture" (alternative pin name "0")
vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1920x1080 fps=10 max s=1920x1080 fps=60.0002
vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1920x1080 fps=10 max s=1920x1080 fps=60.0002
vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1600x1200 fps=10 max s=1600x1200 fps=60.0002
vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1600x1200 fps=10 max s=1600x1200 fps=60.0002
vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1360x768 fps=10 max s=1360x768 fps=60.0002
vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1360x768 fps=10 max s=1360x768 fps=60.0002
vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1280x1024 fps=10 max s=1280x1024 fps=60.0002
vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1280x1024 fps=10 max s=1280x1024 fps=60.0002
vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1280x960 fps=10 max s=1280x960 fps=60.0002
vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1280x960 fps=10 max s=1280x960 fps=60.0002
vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1280x720 fps=10 max s=1280x720 fps=60.0002
vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1280x720 fps=10 max s=1280x720 fps=60.0002
vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1024x768 fps=10 max s=1024x768 fps=60.0002
vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1024x768 fps=10 max s=1024x768 fps=60.0002
vcodec=mjpeg  min s=800x600 fps=10 max s=800x600 fps=60.0002
vcodec=mjpeg  min s=800x600 fps=10 max s=800x600 fps=60.0002
vcodec=mjpeg  min s=720x576 fps=10 max s=720x576 fps=60.0002
vcodec=mjpeg  min s=720x576 fps=10 max s=720x576 fps=60.0002
vcodec=mjpeg  min s=720x480 fps=10 max s=720x480 fps=60.0002
vcodec=mjpeg  min s=720x480 fps=10 max s=720x480 fps=60.0002
vcodec=mjpeg  min s=640x480 fps=10 max s=640x480 fps=60.0002
vcodec=mjpeg  min s=640x480 fps=10 max s=640x480 fps=60.0002
pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=1280x720 fps=10 max s=1280x720 fps=10
pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=1280x720 fps=10 max s=1280x720 fps=10
pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=1920x1080 fps=5 max s=1920x1080 fps=5
pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=1920x1080 fps=5 max s=1920x1080 fps=5
pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=1600x1200 fps=5 max s=1600x1200 fps=5
pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=1600x1200 fps=5 max s=1600x1200 fps=5
pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=1360x768 fps=8 max s=1360x768 fps=8
pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=1360x768 fps=8 max s=1360x768 fps=8
pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=1280x1024 fps=8 max s=1280x1024 fps=8
pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=1280x1024 fps=8 max s=1280x1024 fps=8
pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=1280x960 fps=8 max s=1280x960 fps=8
pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=1280x960 fps=8 max s=1280x960 fps= 8
pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=1024x768 fps=10 max s=1024x768 fps=10
pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=1024x768 fps=10 max s=1024x768 fps=10
pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=800x600 fps=5 max s=800x600 fps=20
pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=800x600 fps=5 max s=800x600 fps=20
pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=720x576 fps=5 max s=720x576 fps=25
pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=720x576 fps=5 max s=720x576 fps=25
pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=720x480 fps=5 max s=720x480 fps=30
pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=720x480 fps=5 max s=720x480 fps=30
pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=640x480 fps=5 max s=640x480 fps=30
pixel_format=yuyv422  min s=640x480 fps=5 max s=640x480 fps=30

My question is:
How to get the proper list in-between min and max ?
Eg:
Please see the below 4 lines.
 vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1920x1080 fps=10 max s=1920x1080 fps=60.0002
 vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1920x1080 fps=10 max s=1920x1080 fps=60.0002
 vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1600x1200 fps=10 max s=1600x1200 fps=60.0002
 vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1600x1200 fps=10 max s=1600x1200 fps=60.0002

It says
min fps=10
max fps=60.0002
Actually it supports below fps:
fps=10.00,
fps=20.00,
fps=25.00,
fps=30.00,
fps=50.00,
fps=60.00

How to guess and get the hidden list like: 20, 25, 30 and 50 ?
If I blindly make a list from guessed values,
Some format doesn't have fps=25 on the list and ffmpeg throw error !
Note:
I can not use C++ or .NET to dig further.
Please suggest me some trick to get the proper list from ffmpeg commands only.
Or any universal guess !


"You can’t post new questions right now"
This is what I see when I try to post a new question today.
Saying my way of questioning is not proper.
Every one in this earth can not be experts in every thing.
If ffmpeg questions are irrelevant to this website, that means my expectation from this website is wrong.
Me too hate your logic on the code block with 4 indentation rules.
Its took me several minutes to understand the logic yesterday even with Youtube for a super simple usage.
If I am the coder, I will auto correct the user input instead of showing errors !
Very bad !!!

Try using ffprobe.exe instead with -print_format json option like this: ffprobe -f dshow -list_options true -i video="USB3.0 capture" -print_format json -v error

Thanks you so much wqw,
I will try this now !

Same result:
{
[dshow @ 08829b00] DirectShow video device options (from video devices)
[dshow @ 08829b00]  Pin "Capture" (alternative pin name "0")
[dshow @ 08829b00]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1920x1080 fps=10 max s=1920x1080 fps=60.0002
[dshow @ 08829b00]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1920x1080 fps=10 max s=1920x1080 fps=60.0002
[dshow @ 08829b00]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1600x1200 fps=10 max s=1600x1200 fps=60.0002
[dshow @ 08829b00]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1600x1200 fps=10 max s=1600x1200 fps=60.0002
[dshow @ 08829b00]   vcodec=mjpeg  min s=1360x768 fps=10 max s=1360x768 fps=60.0002

Weird that output is not JSON formatted at all. Try latest version of ffprobe
